# Duplicated an array and joining it together

Tags: java

I have an array that contains the bytes of a secret message (Hello World, My name is David.). I have another array that have the bytes of a secret code ("secretCode"). The secret code can change, But I have to loop through and XOR each letter of the secret message with the letter of the secretcode.

**Example**

[image]

I need to loop through the secret code array multiple times so that I can XOR each letter of the secret message, how can I do this?

Comment: not clear as to why you need to loop through multiple times for message[i] ^ key[i]?

Comment: @Vikdor key is actually shorter, 'rhubarb'. That's why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String msg = ... ; 
String key = ... ;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(msg.length());
for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
  sb.append((char)(msg.charAt(i) ^ key.charAt(i % key.length())));
}
```

`i % key.length()` will get the chars from key array without going out of bounds.

Comment: Whats the alternative I can use to charAt()? As its a byte array I'm working with

Comment: @GregValantine it's just another array. XOR operator will convert the bytes to an int, you'll just have to cast it to char.
`byte[] byteArr = ...
byte byteAtIndex = byteArr[index];
char c = (char)(byteArr[0] ^ byteArr[1]); // example`